# Will "noindex" tags inside an iframe affect the parent page?

Tags: iframe, web-crawler, nofollow, noindex, search-engine-bots

I have a page on my site that gets loaded in an iframe on the homepage. This page is not supposed to be directly accesible, so I don't want it to show up in search results, so I put "noindex" and "nofollow" tags on it. Will these tags prevent the **parent** page (i.e. the homepage) from being indexed and followed?

Answer (score 0):

I've just been googling for an answer about this... we have just discovered that Google has stopped indexing all the pages on our site that contain an iframe containing a noindex instruction, i.e. the iframe noindex is being applied to the parent page by Google.
If you use Google search console (free) it will tell you if your pages are being indexed or not and why. I'd be interested to know if you see the same as us.